# Single word that depicts the fear of being secretly photographed/surveyed without consent

Tags: single-word-requests, phobias

I am looking for a single word that depicts the fear of *cameras/video recording devices* (spy cameras or surveillance cameras, for example).

To provide additional context, I am writing a short story on "Threats faced by Women", in which a character is afraid of being constantly photographed/surveyed without her consent.

**Example sentence:**

> Sravani's ________phobic, incessantly frightful about being secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores.

I searched within ELU and [elsewhere](http://phobialist.com/). But I could not find a word that matches my requirement accurately.

Comment: This isn't quite how the suffix "phobia" usually works, unless your premise is that Sravani really *is* being secretly photographed and is irrationally frightened by this reality. ("Coulrophobia", for example, is the fear of clowns, not the fear that random people might actually be clowns. "Claustrophobia" is the fear of tight spaces, not the fear that one might be in a tight space. And so on.)

Comment: sounds more like paranoia to me

Comment: @ruakh: Interesting, I've never noticed that "phobia" is the fear of something that you are currently facing, not the fear of facing something that *might* happen. Although the first tends to result the latter.

Comment: You could, perhaps, just rewrite your sentence with the generic word "paranoia."  __Stravani's incessantly frightful, to the point of paranoia, about being photographed in trial rooms at clothing stores.__ It takes the focus off the word and onto the character.

Comment: Actually, none of these are accurate.  A phobia is a fear of something, whether it is happening or not.  An aquaphobe may have an irrational fear of drowning that keeps him out of water entirely - that phobia wouldn't need to be triggered by actual drowning or even being immersed in water at the time.

Emetophobia (fear of vomiting) can trigger extreme anxiety in someone just because they are around someone who is ill, or around an environment where someone may become ill to the point where they could vomit.

Comment: Sravani had an obsessional disorder, she was terrified of being secretly filmed/observed by surveillance cameras...

Comment: Srvani's surveillance phobia....so simple, really. No adjectives here.Your problem was the adjective. And it's surveil, not survey.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to the following [source](https://askthepsych.com/atp/2009/06/17/what-do-you-call-a-fear-of-being-photographed/) there is no specific term for the phobia of being photographed:

> - Technically, a phobia is a fear that is connected to a specific, identifiable object or situation. And although some “lists” of phobias total over 100 items, ***there is no specific term for a fear of being photographed per se***. There are some terms related to the fear of bright lights or of technical equipment such as cameras, but no specific term that is generally accepted which describes the fear of having one’s picture taken.

(askthepsych.com)

You may use the more general:

[Scopophobia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scopophobia), scoptophobia, or ophthalmophobia

> - is an anxiety disorder characterized by a morbid fear of being seen or stared at by others. Scopophobia can also be associated with a pathological fear of drawing attention to oneself.

(wikipedia)

Answer (score 11):

To me, the best word is **surveillance-phobic**.

When used, your example sentence will look as follows:

> Sravani is **surveillance-phobic**, incessantly frightful about being secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores.

Hope this meets your purpose.

Comment: surveillance phobia, not phobic.

Comment: @lambie One who has the phobia is a phobic. In the instant example sentence, the right word will be "surveillance-phobic", not "surveillance-phobia".

Comment: This is not grammatical: //Sravani's surveillance-phobic // Period. This, on the other hand, is grammatical: Sravani's surveillance-phobic  life [noun] as a Delhi resident......if you use surveillance-PHOBIC here, you  need a noun to make it grammatical.

Comment: @lambie Sravani's = Sravani is. Now, I think I have been able to make the thing clear to you.

Comment: No, you have not. You have made a mistake and are trying to correct me when the mistake is  yours. THIS: /Sravani's surveillance-phobic, incessantly frightful about being secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores/ is NOT grammatical in English and the 14 upvotes are just mistaken.

Comment: @Lambie. Where did I make the mistake? How is the sentence not grammatical? Upvotes have not been given by you. Then, how could you say that they were "just mistaken"?

Comment: /Sravani's surveillance-phobic, incessantly frightful about being secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores/ =not grammatical.

Comment: Grammatical: Sravani's  surveillance phobia and incessantly frightened state of mind etc.

Comment: Grammatical: Sravani's surveillance-phobic, incessantly frightened state of mind.

Comment: Frightful is also an ENGLISH mistake. The OP meant: frightened, most likely and not frightful. What a frightful mess this is now.

Comment: @Lambie. Contrary to what you say, I reiterate that my sentence "[Sravani is] surveillance-phobic, incessantly frightful about being secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores" is perfectly grammatical. You have given examples of what could instead be grammatical, which, I agree, are grammatical too. As you have not explained how my sentence is ungrammatical, I do not venture upon explaining how my sentence is grammatical. This issue apart, what about your claim that the 14 upvotes were just mistaken? How can you claim that, when you do not own them?

Comment: Your ANSWER was not written properly.  You wrote: Sravani's surveillance-phobic. GO LOOK AT IT. Sravani IS surveillance phobic, is FINE. But not with the apostrophe s, for IS. It would not work.

Answer (score 6):

If you are "stuck" on one-word options, you might need to limit yourself to neologisms, such as the following:

> - videophobe
> - cameraphobe
> - photophobe (or photophobic)

On the other hand, if you're willing to step outside the box, you might consider

> - surveillance phobia (surveillance phobic) [great minds think alike, Dinesh Kumar Garg!)
> - photographic paranoia (or phobia)
> - filmic paranoia (or phobia)
> - Peeping Tom phobia

Comment: Photophobia is fear of light though; this isn't that simple :)

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps, you could substitute it for the fear of being watched/observed. From wikipedia,

> Scopophobia, scoptophobia, or ophthalmophobia is an anxiety disorder
>   characterized by a morbid fear of being seen or stared at by others

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, there is no specific term for fear of secret cameras or being supervised.

If acceptable, you could use a neologism; coin a new term.

Since phobia names come from Greek<sup><sup><sup>*thanks to @AakashM*</sup></sup></sup> and Latin, you can add up two words.

For instance, [*vigilare*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vigilare) means *to supervise* or *to monitor* in Latin. By adding `-phobia` to it we get **vigilophobia**.

If you want to take a Greek root, the `επιβλέπω (epivlépo)` means *supervise*. So I guess you could use **epivlepophobia**.

However, *vigilophobia* gives one result on Google, while *epivlepophobe* doesn't.

<sup><sub>*If you know Greek, please correct me if I am wrong.*</sub></sup>

Comment: Phobia names come from Greek. The `ph` is the giveaway.

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using "fear of [***voyeurism***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyeurism)" which fits in the context where she might be secretly photographed/video-recorded by a voyeur/Peeping Tom.

> Voyeurism is the sexual interest in or practice of spying on people
>   engaged in intimate behaviors, such as undressing, sexual activity, or
>   other actions usually considered to be of a private nature.[1]
>
> The voyeur does not normally interact directly with the subject of
>   his/her interest, who is often unaware of being observed. The essence
>   of voyeurism is the observing but ***may also involve the making of a
>   secret photograph or video of the subject during an intimate activity***.

Your example:

> Sravani ***has fear of voyeurism***, incessantly frightful about being
>   secretly photographed in Trial Rooms at Clothing Stores.

Or "fear of [***Peeping Tom***](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peeping_tom)":

> A person who watches another without the other's permission and
>   usually without the other's knowledge, especially for the purpose of
>   deriving sexual pleasure from the sight of the other.

[Wikipedia, Wiktionary]

Comment: Sravani is also paranoid about smartphone cameras in public places. So I was really looking for a specific *phobia* that would define this. I am afraid Peeping Toms / Voyeurism are specific and not generic.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy As commented by ruakh, phobia doesn't work in the context. I would prefer ***camera-phobia*** to ***surveillance-phobia***. Surveillance has a special connotation that doesn't fit in your context. ***Other-phobia*** would not work, either I am afraid.

Comment: +1 I agree that *phobia* doesn’t work here. My understanding of a phobia is that it is an unreasonable fear of something that **normally isn’t scary**. Peeping toms/voyeurism/[being under] surveillance are normally scary, so being afraid of them wouldn't qualify as phobias, making your answers correct. I think her only “phobia” is her fear of “fitting/trial rooms” (& of “public places” as per OP’s comment to you) **caused by** her fear of surveillance/voyeurism/peeping toms (just as aquaphobia isn't the fear of drowning but rather a fear of **water** [perhaps] caused by a fear of drowning).

Answer (score 2):

***Fotografizophobia*** - is the only work I know which means to have an unreasoning fear of photographs or of having your photograph taken.  I have never encountered anyone with this phobia nor found a documented case of someone having an actual phobia of having their photograph taken, though I am aware of and have met people who will culturally not allow themselves to be photographed as their beliefs state they lose a portion/all of their soul, or that their soul is bound every/any time a photograph is taken.

Comment: Actually, I know people with this phobia. Also, a quick Google search shows up forums in which such phobias are discussed.

Answer (score 0):

I think **shutter-shy** ought to do the job by itself.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. A good answer here will be supported by an explanation that may include an quote from an authoritative reference.